# Packer not booting Win10

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, packer

I'm trying to use Packer form Hashicorp to create VMs. The idea is that I can create Windows 10 VMs for for each of my assignments, and run those VMs on my "main" Windows 10. I have access to Hyper-V, and as of late 2016, Packer supports that too.

Grabbing several files from [Matt Wrock's Github repository](https://github.com/mwrock/packer-templates), I have created a json file, an Autounattend and some scripts. When running Packer, I ended up with an error saying "Error getting WinRM host: No ip address". This had gone on for 5+ hours, so something was not going right. Interestingly, the Hyper-V Manger said that the VM was there, and I could even log in. Then I noticed that none of install scripts had been executed. For instance, in my Autounattend I execute Matt's boxstarter.ps1 script to install Boxstarter, but Boxstarter has not been installed.

To get a better visual on the process, I changed the Autounattend.xml to have all WillShowUI properties set to true. Nothing appears. To me this seems like Windows 10 is not booted. Any idea how I can check this? Also, from a [different Github repository](https://github.com/jacqinthebox/packer-templates/blob/master/templates/hyperv-windows_server_2016.json), I found in a json file for Windows Server 2013 the "boot_command" with value aaa. Without having any idea whether this applies to Windows 10 as well, I put that in my json file too. Maybe this boot command is wrong?

Alternatively, is there anyone out there having a public repository which I can use to create Windows 10 VMs that will run on Hyper-V on a Windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some good news :) You don't need to build Packer from source for the Hyper-V provisioner. It was merged in at version 0.12.1 so if you have the latest you're good to go.

Here are some samples that I used when testing it for version 0.12.1+:

- https://github.com/StefanScherer/packer-windows - Samples for Windows 10 & Windows Server 2016 set up with Docker & Windows containers
- Ubuntu 16.04, hyperv-iso, generation 2 (UEFI) https://github.com/taliesins/packer-baseboxes/blob/master/hyperv-ubuntu-16.04.json

Feel free to ping me on GitHub (@patricklang) with issues in any of those repos.

Comment: Finally nailed it; the files in Stefan Scherer's repository helped me quite a lot. They contained all the info I needed and not a lot of extra scripting to get me going.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough details to tell what's wrong.

Try using [taliesins basebox - Windows 10](https://github.com/taliesins/packer-baseboxes/blob/master/hyperv-windows-10-amd64.json), he is the main author of the Hyper-V support in Packer and I expect his examples to work.